# What project level configuration is required to display svg image

Tags: html, css, svg, mime-types, web.xml

**Issue:** The svg image is not displaying on HTML page after I deployed application on the server.

**Description:** After digging into the issue, I came to know that it is not browser issue. Rather it is server configuration issue where mime type "image/svg+xml" is not set up for "svg" extention.
I checked the inspect element -> Network -> Logo.svg. The type is showing as plain for the svg image. When checked on my local netbeans server, it works fine i.e. type is showing as svg.

**Query:** Since, I don't have the admin rights of the server domain, how can I configure my code to display the svg image at project level?
I added MIME mapping in web.xml of project but it didn't work. Is there any more configuration required to set up MIME at project level?

Server- Weblogic 10.3.6.0 (SOA 11g)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can map mime types using a `mime-mapping` element in your `web.xml` file.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/web_xml.html#1017395

Comment: As mentioned in query above, I have added mime type in web.xml file as follows:   `<mime-mapping><extension>.svg</extension><mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type></mime-mapping>`.  But it is not working. I also tried 'svg' instead of '.svg' but no help.

Comment: My apologies. I missed that.